# Find all columns with name X and fill with values, but increment each column

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the newest excel.

I have a structure such as this:

```
| ID |  Day  |  Value | Day | Value | Day | Value.............| Day | Value |
   1             val           val            val                       val
   2             val           val            val                       val
   3             val           val            val                       val
```

I need the data to look like this

```
| ID |  Day  |  Value | Day | Value | Day | Value.............| Day | Value |
   1     1       val     2     val     3      val                 N     val
   2     1       val     2     val     3      val                 N     val
   3     1       val     2     val     3      val                 N     val
```

Essentially I need to go to the first day column and add a 1 for all the ID, then go to the second day column and incremnt by 1 and write 2 for all id. This is going to be repeated. Manually I can do this by putting a 1 then drag down, put a 2 and drag down. The problem is I have a couple of thousand day columns so it will be very time consuming. Is there an automated way to accomplish this task?

Comment: you can do anything with vba, but thousands of columns seems a bit excessive. How do you have the data originally? If you can get it in a narrow format such as ID | DAY | VALUE, you could calculate the day using the CountIF function, then use a pivot table to display your desired results

Comment: It has to be in this format as this is a data dictionary for a system and it has to follow this procedure. This is an unorthodox way we created the system, but for this specific use case it has to be in this format.

Comment: Do you know that "Day" will always be every other column? ie. B, D, F, H, J, etc.

Comment: Yes it will be every 2nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VBA code you could use (replacing appropriate values for LastRow and LastCol):

```
Dim LastRow as Integer, LastCol as Integer, Count as Integer
LastRow = 100
LastCol = 100
Count = 1
For i = 2 to LastRow
    For t = 2 to LastCol step 2
        Cells(i,t).Value = Count
        Count = Count + 1
    Next t
    Count = 1
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Not automated but quite quick. Assuming `ID` is in A1. Add a row (say Row1) with series fill and sort columns by Row2. Series fill Row3 columns for `Days` and copy down to suit. Sort columns by Row1 and delete Row1.